# Player component plays with an echo when rendered in a loop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, html5-video, ref

I am trying to invoke a player component for the form fields that has `.m3u8` in its value. In my case, 2 of the form fields end up showing the play button.
When I try to click the Play icon of one of the fields, it begins to play but I hear double sound/echo in the video. The player component has `ref` attribute  on its `<div>` and my suspicion is that when I click the play button, the player gets triggered for both the fields at the same time.

When I try to render the player for only one form field, it works all good. I am not sure how to resolve the echo issue. Please help. Here's my code:

```
Formfields.js
-------------
const initPlay = (item) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <MediaComponent
          playUrl={item.value}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }

<table>
  <tbody>
    {formFields.map(prop =>
      <tr key={prop.id}>
        <td>{prop.name}</td>
        <td>{typeof prop.value == "string" && prop.value?.includes('m3u8') ?
          initPlay(prop) : null}
        </td>
      </tr>
    )}
  </tbody>
</table>


MediaComponent.js
-----------------
const MediaComponent = ({ playUrl }) => {
  
  const playMedia = useCallback(() => {
   // Pass src url to player hook 
    setSrc(playUrl)
    setVisible(true)
  }, [playUrl, setSrc, setVisible])

  return (
    <div>
      <span
        onClick={() => playUrl()}
        style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
      >
        <Icon name="play”/>
      </span>
      <Player/> // This is the Player component that I am talking about
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

The echo was because the `<Player/>` component was added to every field that had the `m3u8` string. The right thing to do is to have the Player component defined at the parent level in `FormFields.js` right before the `</table>` tag ends. This way we can make sure that only one instance of Player is available to all the fields and on click of the play button we can set the player rolling.